# Should I have two accounts in my NAS (ex.: Bob as user and Poseidon as admin, both controlled by me)?

Tags: account-security, user-management

I have a Synology NAS running in a SOHO network and I'd like to maintain it secure. First thing I did was disable the default admin and guest accounts, second I created some accounts and this is what I currently have:

- Bob (this is me): admin + user roles
- Charlie: user role
- Dana: user role

I use the account `Bob` on a daily basis and I don't like the idea of using an admin account this way so I was thinking about creating a new admin user that will only be controlled by me and have the following structure:

- Poseidon (this is me): admin role
- Bob (this is me): user role
- Charlie: user role
- Dana: user role

Is this the right way to handle the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable practice. Just be sure that the password on the two accounts Bob has access to are different *and* that both (but especially the admin account) accounts have strong/complex passwords.

Also don't forget to rotate passwords periodically.

Comment: Oh yes, I enforce password strength using Synology CP and I use LastPass so the passwords I set for admin accounts are always randomly generated with 30 chars including letters, numbers and special characters. 

PS: I know some would argue against LastPass but that's what I currently have, I know the issues surrounding the service but it's all about a trade-off.

Comment: While there is a marginal benfit from using different passwords in this context, this is small relative to the benefit of privilege seperation from using 2 accounts.

Comment: @symcbean I'm not sure there is much point in privilege separation if the accounts have the same password. Testing for pw reuse is pretty much pentesting 101.

Comment: I agree with @Hollowproc. I believe that having duped passwords is never a good idea, no matter the situation.